# Default Document not working on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a simple azure web app and have set the default document in the portal to home.aspx.  There is a home.aspx file published, it is browsable via `http://my-domain.azurewebsites.net/home.aspx` (not real domain) however the default document won't work when browsing to http://my-domain.azurewebsites.net it returns a 404.  There is nothing special here.   I even added it to the web.confg and it still returns a 404.  It is a web forms project, set to integrated security with the correct default document added.  Any ideas?

Comment: As a simpler test to help isolate, does it work if all you have is `foo.html` and set that as a default doc?

Comment: Does not work with an existing html file either.

Comment: Can you share the web app name ([indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) if you prefer)?

Comment: @DavidEbbo I see now how it will help.  I setup the following web app (West):  supportforlucuma   There is only one other app in that plan which is the one that isn't working.  /home.aspx and /home.html are both valid entries and the default docs are there.

Comment: Looks like that's the complex app with everything. Since you were able to repro in an app with just one html file, that's the one we should look at to take everything else out of the equation. In fact, you could use your `supportforlucuma` test app for that.

Comment: It isn't a complex app though. It is only an html theme from a theme site and a simple aspx page.   Nothing more.

Comment: It's all about isolating. This will tell us whether issue is in App Service platform or specific to your app. Just throw a home.html in an empty clean app, add the default document and see if that works.

Comment: Will do and will let you know.

Comment: BTW, your app is not that trivial. You have a web.config that does all kind of things. e.g. it has a `defaultDocument` section with `<add value="~/home.aspx" />`, which not only is probably not valid (~ syntax), but conflicts with what you're setting in Azure. Other parts of web.config could play a part as well. Did you try running it in your local IIS with default document? My guess is that it wouldn't work either.

Comment: I added that to the web config to test it when the azure app settings weren't working. I'm pretty sure the dev just created a new web form app added the aspx page and that's it. I'll try on the support app regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I setup the following web app (West): supportforlucuma There is only one other app in that plan which is the one that isn't working.

I can see the home.html page by visit “http://supportforlucuma.azurewebsites.net/”, Is your issue solved? If no, I will provide more information of how to debug this issue.

Except to set default document on portal and web.config, the default document also could be set in RouteConfig.cs file. For example, following code will set the index.aspx as the default page of current web application and it has the highest priority.  If index.aspx file is not exist, a 404 error will response to client. Please check whether the similar code is exist in   RouteConfig.cs file.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("default", "{page}", "~/{page}.aspx",false,new RouteValueDictionary( new { page = "index" }));
```

For further troubleshooting this issue, we can to get the detail information of 404 response. For example, which modules are executed on server side during the default page is accessed.  To do it, we need to enable Failed request tracing.  Then we could see the detail information by download the tracing log from LogFiles folder. For example, "ftp://xx.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/LogFiles/W3SVC355162095/".